# GridViewItem IsSelected binding in UWP App

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

We have a requirement to display the images  in a `GridView` incrementally. So to find the selected items in `GridView` , `IsSelected` property of the `GridView` item has bind with corresponding binding objects property of `CLR object` (property of the `GridView's ItemSource` type). Since, `UWP` does not support `RelativeSouce` and setter binding in style, so after doing some search on internet we found the below code.

```
public class GridViewEx : GridView
{

        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
            var gridItem = element as GridViewItem;

            var binding = new Binding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = item, Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected") };
            gridItem.SetBinding(SelectorItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
        }

}
```

But it seems that there is a flaw with the above approach. Whenever the page is being scrolled down to load next set of photos then the previous selected items are losing their selection.

Is anyone has  experienced this issue before or any suggestions to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Move `IsSelected` to the model class and bind it to a user control. The user control actually is the cell and will be put in your data template.

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <controls:MyCustomControl IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

In `MyCustomControl`, you will handle difference visual state to show the selected status of item. This way your ViewModel dont have to "know" the list at all, when you need just get list of selected item from your list of models.

Comment: But how to bind to GridViewItem.IsSelectedProperty to set IsSelected in background for any user selected item at page?

Comment: when user tap on the Item, get the model, get the IsSelected property, set it to true. Forget about `GridViewItem.IsSelectedProperty`, it have nothing to do as I ignore it in my sample.

Comment: Anyone? this is vital for almost every application I know and there's no reliable way to do it.